# SqlDataReader always read as false

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

I can't figure out why this function resulting wrong, even though it's seem right.

There's nothing wrong with this. Any solution?

Nothing wrong with the connection string or SQL related function. There's something wrong with my function. I use SQL Server.

`ESEMKABank > Employee`:

```
EmployeeId    int IDENTITY(1, 1)
Username      nvarchar(64)
Password      nvarchar(64)
FullName      nvarchar(64)
RoleId        int                     -- <-- FOREIGN KEY
```

For VB.NET:

```vb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form_Login

    'Dimensions
    Dim theConnection As New SqlConnection
    Dim theCommand As New SqlCommand
    Dim theDataReader As SqlDataReader
    Dim theDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter

    'Initialization
    Private Sub Form_Login_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        theConnection.ConnectionString = "SERVER = MORGAN\SQLEXPRESS; DATABASE = ESEMKABank; INTEGRATED SECURITY = TRUE;"

        'Parameterize
        theCommand.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Me.TextBox_Username.Text
        theCommand.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Me.TextBox_Password.Text

    End Sub

    'Login
    Private Sub Button_Login_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_Login.Click
        If Me.TextBox_Username.Text = "" Or Me.TextBox_Password.Text = "" Then
            Me.PictureBox_Wrong.Visible = True
        Else
            Using theDataReader

                'Declaration
                theCommand.Connection = theConnection
                theCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Username, Password FROM Employee WHERE Username = @Username AND Password = @Password"
                theConnection.Open()
                theDataReader = theCommand.ExecuteReader()

                If theDataReader.Read() Then

                    'Dispose!
                    theCommand.Dispose()
                    theConnection.Close()
                    SqlConnection.ClearPool(theConnection)

                    Me.PictureBox_Wrong.Visible = False
                Else

                    'Dispose!
                    theCommand.Dispose()
                    theConnection.Close()
                    SqlConnection.ClearPool(theConnection)

                    Me.PictureBox_Wrong.Visible = True
                End If
            End Using
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Could you try replacing the query for a "SELECT 1"? just as a test

Comment: alright let me try

Comment: the result is = Wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't set the parameter values in Form_Load. At this point they're just empty strings. Set the parameter values *after* you set the `.CommandText` property.

While I'm here, let's say the user mis-types their password on the first attempt. This code will *always* fail on the second attempt — even if they have corrected the password — because you have disposed the connection. In .Net, the best practice is to use a completely new connection object in most cases (also enclosed in a `Using` block), so that you can avoid this type of problem and take advantage of connection pooling.

Finally, this code implies you are storing the password in plain text, rather than using a salted hash. That is so incredibly wrong that I'm not even gonna leave sample code showing the other fixes, because I don't want to leave behind examples of doing username/password checks for others to see that don't involve hashed passwords.

Comment: Lol problem fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Not _all_ the problem.

Comment: Read the 2nd two paragraphs in my answer.

Comment: Don't declare Dim in Class?

Comment: But it's not efficient. You know, it such a burden to Re-declare a connection object.

Comment: No, it's not a burden. It's **way** more expensive to re-negotiate a connection with the server. Even just opening the connection costs a lot more. On the other hand, sharing or re-using your own connection objects leads to bottlenecks and holding connections open too long. Connection pooling exists to allow the .Net runtime to manage this for you... no bottlenecks, and minimal round trips between your program and the server.

Comment: And don't forget the third paragraph.

Comment: So you are assuming that I need to re-declare the Command and Connection and SqlReader and so?

Comment: I've just used the Parameter, there's a better way to make mine secure?!

Comment: Yes, you should re-declare those objects. Yes, there is some overhead there, but again: it's much lower than extra network latency. As for Parameters... they mitigate against _one_ kind of attack. They are important. You should absolutely use them. But you should also never never **NEVER** store passwords in plain text. To store a password, you pre-pend a unique (per-user) salt and cryptographically (ie: not md5 or sha1; you want bcrypt or scrypt) hash the result, and store that. When someone tries to log in, you do the same thing with the attempted password and compare the hashes.

Comment: Alright thanks for the advice! I might learn that scrypt as well.